# Unable to build my-sql-connector-c++ with CMake

Tags: c++, mysql, cmake

**Introduction**

I am trying to connect and interact with a mysql db running on my local, in a c++ project.  I am also using cmake to compile my project.

**Preparation**

I installed mysqlconnector cpp by using mysql-connector-odbc-8.0.25-macos11-x86-64bit.dmg from their community downloads. I have the include and lib files available at /usr/local/mysql-connector-c+

**CmakeLists.txt**

Part of my CMakeLists.txt which deals with mysqlconnector is referenced below:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13.4 FATAL_ERROR)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR "/usr/local/mysql-connector-c++")
include_directories(${FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR}/include)
link_directories(${FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR}/lib64)
add_executable(runservice main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(runservice mysqlcppconn)
```

The `cmake` command runs fine.

**Build Error**

When I try to build using '''make``` command, I get the following error :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "mysqlx::abi2::r0::common::Value::print(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const", referenced from:
      mysqlx::abi2::r0::Value::print(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const in main.cpp.o
      construction vtable for mysqlx::abi2::r0::common::Value-in-mysqlx::abi2::r0::Value in main.cpp.o
  "typeinfo for mysqlx::abi2::r0::common::Value", referenced from:
      construction vtable for mysqlx::abi2::r0::common::Value-in-mysqlx::abi2::r0::Value in main.cpp.o
      typeinfo for mysqlx::abi2::r0::Value in main.cpp.o
  "vtable for mysqlx::abi2::r0::DbDoc", referenced from:
      mysqlx::abi2::r0::Value::~Value() in main.cpp.o
      __GLOBAL__sub_I_main.cpp in main.cpp.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [runservice] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/runservice.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I can't understand this error or how to go about solving this.

***Thank you for your precious time***

Comment: Shouldn't it be `target_link_libraries(runservice  libmysqlcppconn8` or `target_link_libraries(runservice  libmysqlcppconn8.1` if you follow the documentation.

Comment: I tried the above, it still gives the same error.

Comment: I was able to build with mysqlcppconn8, Thank you for your comment.

Comment: My typo, I forgot to remove the prefix lib.